# Xcode 8.3 macOS Project without storyboard

Tags: xcode8, macos-sierra

I am trying to find a way to start a project in Xcode 8.3.1 (8E1000a) using .xib files instead of storyboards in Objective-C on macOS.

There isn't a clearcut way to do it, and everything I've seen is iOS using single view storyboard application.

I'm hoping you guys have a fix or at least a quick hack.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update in 2018: **In Xcode 9, the Use Storyboards option is back!**

This does not apply to all templates, for example the Game template, but it is in the normal Cocoa App template.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to keep a copy of Xcode 8.2 around to create new projects. Create the project in 8.2. Develop the project in 8.3.

If you're going to use Xcode 8.3 to create new projects, you'll have to manually remove the storyboard and add xib files to the project. You'll also have to tell the project to use one of your xib files as the main interface file for the project. The following discussion on Apple's developer forums shows you how to do this:

[Did Xcode 8.3 update eliminate the basic AppDelegate project template?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/74868)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Basically Xcode is proposing you some templates when you create a new project.
And there are all using Storyboards.

However, you can definitely use xib files in your project.

I myself use xib files because it is so much simpler when your project is under version control.

Storyboard + Version Control = Mess